# Calling a static method from a method within the same class

Tags: java

What would be the best way to call a static method named `eatApples` from a method called `main` within a class called `Apples`

Is there any difference between `Apples.eatApples();` and `eatApples();`, regarding efficiency or any other thing in general?

Comment: Excuse me, you are asking the wrong question. If you are having performance issues, you should look elsewhere for optimization. If you are not having performance issues, you should write the code the way you find more readable. Personally I find the shorter variant more readable, but opinions may differ.

Comment: The key difference is readability for other coders.

Comment: @FNER compilers are very smart, they optimize far better than you will. Write your code as readable as possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are actually 3 ways to write it:

```
Apples.eatApples();

eatApples();

this.eatApples();   // Don't do this!
```

They all mean exactly the same thing and have identical performance.  The only difference is readability.

- The first one makes it clear to the reader that a `static` method is being called (assuming that you follow standard Java naming convention!)
- The second one is less clear, but you can easily look for the declaration to check if the method is static or not.
- The third one is misleading.  Using `this` is "flagging" to the reader that the method is an instance method.  But it isn't.

Answer (score 4):

There won't be any difference between the bytecode generated for `Apples.eatApples();` and `eatApples();`. Performance wise both would be same.

Comment: This can easily be verified with `javap -v`.

Comment: If you want to call eatApples as is, then its obviously from another static method, in the same class. Apples.eatApples() used to call this method from other classes.